# TFS: Branch without check-in

Tags: tfs, branch, checkin

I'm going to create a new (vc)project which will start as a copy of another project.
I want to have the possibility to simply merge changes between these two projects, although they are inside another big branch.

I want to do this by branching, but when I do branch from ui, the branch is created and immediately checked-in. I don't want to do this.

Is it possible to make pending change of type "branch" without checking-in?

Comment: it seem that there is a possibility to do a [branch for folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181409(v=vs.100).aspx) which makes the pending change of type "branch"...

Answer (score 1):

Branches are created on the serverside so they are automatically checked in. I would recommend using 2 shelvesets and setting up a secondary workspace where you can merge the two shelvesets.